# How to insert images and text using IF Else

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a Web based programming which require to create a quiz and survey. As a admin, i need to create a quiz which i can insert question and images. It integrated with a Web Service

The problem is when inserting just the text, it will automatically insert an images into the database without selecting any images and i do not know where the images is coming from.

Can u guys check what is the problem?..

```
    byte[] answerImage = new byte[0];
    String answer = TextBox1.Text;
    Boolean correctAnswer = Convert.ToBoolean(DropDownList1.Text);
    int questionId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["questionID"]);

    try
    {

        if (AsyncFileUpload1.FileBytes != null)
        {
            answerImage = new byte[AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength];
            answerImage = AsyncFileUpload1.FileBytes;

            this.ws.createAnswerForAnswer(answer, answerImage, correctAnswer, questionId);

        }
        else
        {
            this.ws.createAnswerForAnswer(answer, answerImage, correctAnswer, questionId);
        }

        {
            Label5.Text = "Succesfully Inserted";
            TextBox1.Text = "";
            Response.Redirect("CreateAnswer.aspx");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You gave insufficient information. Are bytes of image sent through ws correct or something rubbish? What `FileBytes` contains in both cases?

Comment: As Sarrus said we need more; where is the method signature this is in?